# Chow pup drinking

Tags: dogs

Hi just got a [Chow Chow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_Chow) puppy. Everything is great apart from messy drinking. Does anybody have any tips to stop him dipping his mane into his drinking water?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many successful methods, however there are some preventions with minimal success or methods that reduce the amount of consequences.

This may not be a very plausible answer depending on your puppy's snout, however after researching other sources, one of the solutions that could potentially help is getting yourself a glass tupperware container with a removable rubber (example here: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZON0.jpg)). You would have to cut out a circular hole that is big enough for your puppy's snout to fit into it. This could work as whenever your dog goes to drink out of it, the mane would be pushed back, and so it will stay out of water. However, once again, I am concerned that this solution may not be plausible for your puppy's snout as from the looks of it, chow puppies have nearly flat snouts.

You can also give less water in a bowl a go, if this is possible. If you do it, it's possible that your dog's mane won't dip into the water as much as it would with the regular amount of water in the bowl.

Source: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/dogs/comments/2ay6ca/how_do_it_keep_my_dogs_from_slopping_water_on_the/)

Answer (score 2):

Make his water bowl sit up off the ground. Other than that, especially in the summer, get used to it and shave the bottom of his neck a bit for his comfort as well. It's hilarious, they are a mess! You will get slobbered on for the rest of his life, it's pure fun!